# Can I use Instagram API when I don't have an application?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want to build an application for my client but it is a website (using php + mysql) to manage his Instagram. We don't build android & iOS apps.
Is it still possible to get `Instagram API`?

In their documentation they say "Register your application".

Comment: An application can also be a web application.

Comment: What kind of administration would you like to perform? Remember, you cannot post from any app, beside native mobile app by Instagram itself.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to register your application for an API key.

Remember that an application can be a desktop application, or a mobile application, or a web application.